# How to Pass initialPreview Data in bootstrap-fileinput

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-file-input

I have a page that allows users to edit a property listing they had previously submitted. I've been using bootstrap-fileinput to allow users to add images, and it will use the initialPreview attribute to show images that they've already uploaded. Users can remove the initialPreview images to remove images from the dropzone, but I can't find a way to pass this info to the server, that the user has removed these initialPreview images.

I've tried uploadExtraData: function() {}
But I can't get any information about the initialPreview images. Also, I am using the Laravel 5.7 PHP framework for my website.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="additional_info" class="col-lg-12 control-label">Add Photos to Attract Lender Interest</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" multiple class="image" data-overwrite-initial="false"
               data-min-file-count="0" value="{{ $mortgage->close_date}}">
    </div>
</div>
{{-- Scripts for the pretty file input plugin called bootstrap-fileinput --}}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.7/js/fileinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.5.2/themes/fas/theme.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#image").fileinput({
        overwriteInitial: false,
        initialPreview: [
            // IMAGE DATA
            "http://digitalbroker.test/storage/properties/847%20Queen%20Street%20West,%20Toronto,%20ON,%20Canada_1.JPG",
            // IMAGE DATA
            "http://digitalbroker.test/storage/properties/847%20Queen%20Street%20West,%20Toronto,%20ON,%20Canada_2.JPG",
        ],
        initialPreviewAsData: true, // identify if you are sending preview data only and not the raw markup
        initialPreviewFileType: 'image', // image is the default and can be overridden in config below
        initialPreviewDownloadUrl: 'http://kartik-v.github.io/bootstrap-fileinput-samples/samples/{filename}', // includes the dynamic `filename` tag to be replaced for each config
        showUpload: false,
        theme: 'fas',
        uploadUrl: "/submit-mortgage",
        uploadExtraData: function () {
            return {
                _token: $("input[name='_token']").val(),
            };
        },
        allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'],
        overwriteInitial: true,
        showCaption: false,
        showRemove: true,
        maxFileSize: 5000,
        maxFilesNum: 8,
        fileActionSettings: {
            showRemove: true,
            showUpload: false,
            showZoom: true,
            showDrag: false,
        },
        slugCallback: function (filename) {
            return filename.replace('(', '_').replace(']', '_');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Right now it just removes any old images upon submit and will save any newly uploaded ones. I'd like to both keep track of what initialPreview images were not removed, and which new images were uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but for those who stumble upon it here is a solution:

When a user clicks the remove button on the `initialPreview` frame you can pass information from that to the server by adding additional option to `fileinput` which will make an Ajax call each time the remove button is clicked.

Using the question above you would need to add:

```
initialPreviewConfig: [
   {
  // This is passed to the server in the request body as key: 0
     key: 0, 

  // This is the url that you would send a POST request to that will handle the call.
     url: 'http://www.example.com/image/remove', 

  // Any extra data that you would like to add to the POST request
     extra: {
         key: value
     }
   }
]
```

You would need to create an object for each item you have within your `initialPreview` array.

The OP's `.fileinput` would become:

```
$("#image").fileinput({
        overwriteInitial: false,
        initialPreview: [
            // IMAGE DATA
            "http://digitalbroker.test/storage/properties/847%20Queen%20Street%20West,%20Toronto,%20ON,%20Canada_1.JPG",
            // IMAGE DATA
            "http://digitalbroker.test/storage/properties/847%20Queen%20Street%20West,%20Toronto,%20ON,%20Canada_2.JPG",
        ],
        initialPreviewConfig: [
            {
               key: 0,
               url: '/image/remove', //custom URL
               extra: {
                   image: '847 Queen Street West, Toronto, ON, Canada_1.JPG
               }
             },
            {
               key: 1,
               url: '/image/remove', //custom URL
               extra: {
                   image: 847 Queen Street West, Toronto, ON, Canada_2.JPG
               }
             },
        ],
        initialPreviewAsData: true, // identify if you are sending preview data only and not the raw markup
        initialPreviewFileType: 'image', // image is the default and can be overridden in config below
        initialPreviewDownloadUrl: 'http://kartik-v.github.io/bootstrap-fileinput-samples/samples/{filename}', // includes the dynamic `filename` tag to be replaced for each config
        showUpload: false,
        theme: 'fas',
        uploadUrl: "/submit-mortgage",
        uploadExtraData: function () {
            return {
                _token: $("input[name='_token']").val(),
            };
        },
        allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'],
        overwriteInitial: true,
        showCaption: false,
        showRemove: true,
        maxFileSize: 5000,
        maxFilesNum: 8,
        fileActionSettings: {
            showRemove: true,
            showUpload: false,
            showZoom: true,
            showDrag: false,
        },
        slugCallback: function (filename) {
            return filename.replace('(', '_').replace(']', '_');
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps anybody who comes across it.

FYI this is my first answer on SO (please be kind :P )